# How can I safely overload a constructor with enums? C#

Tags: c#, constructor, enums, overloading

I have this code

```
public enum MyEnumOne : byte { ... }
public enum MyEnumTwo : byte { ... }

public class MyClass
{
    public readonly MyEnumOne E1;
    public readonly MyEnumTwo E2;

    private MyClass(MyEnumOne e1)
    {
        E1 = e1;
    }

    private MyClass(MyEnumTwo e2)
    {
        E2 = e2;
    }

    public static MyClass CreateWithE1(MyEnumOne e1)
    {
        return new MyClass(e1);
    }

    public static MyClass CreateWithE2(MyEnumTwo e2)
    {
        return new MyClass(e2);
    }
}
```

How can I be sure that this code will always cast the correct constructor overload?

```
var A = MyClass.CreateWithE1(0);
var B = MyClass.CreateWithE2(0);
```

I can ensure this by making the class mutable, but I do not need the class to be mutable.

Note: If I made any mistakes making the class immutable please to tell me :)

Edit: Both enums have their first element to `None = 0` and there are legit cases where an instance with an enum to `None` could be created.

Comment: I think it is safe enough. Since you are using `MyEnumOne` and `MyEnumTwo` as parameter type. Are you getting any warning for ambiguous call ?

Comment: Or are you worried about calling `CreateWithE1` with a *value* that only exists in `E2`?

Comment: How could it possibly *not* use the right constructor overload?  If you pass in an object typed to `MyEnumOne` how could it possibly call the `MyEnumTwo` overload?  If you tried to explicitly call that overload (by removing the other) it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The methods have different names, so there's no risk to remove in the first place.  And if he were trying to overload a method/constructor he'd get a compile time ambiguity error, to which you're just masking with a runtime error.

Comment: Love the failing factory - also add an `[Obsolete("Don't call with an int", true)]` to cause the compiler to fail it.

Comment: @plinth The compiler would fail already if you just don't add it, as it creates an ambiguity error.

Comment: This article [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/01/26/c.net-little-pitfalls-implicit-zero-to-enum-conversion.aspx) and the fact that I didn't find a similar case on SO or the internet made me post it

Comment: @warcraker see my answer. I am using this kind of methodology in a production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `CreateWithE1` is *compiled*, it contains a call to the `MyEnumOne`-based constructor.

Similarly, when `CreateWithE2` is *compiled*, it contains a call to the `MyEnumTwo`-based constructor.

When either of these methods is *called*, the constructor to use has already been fixed in place, and is not based on the runtime *value* of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When calling any overloaded method with [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion, as there is between int and enum, the compiler infers the method you want based on convertable types just as it does when you call a method directly. If, however, it encounters an ambiguity, well, it'll throw just that error - "ambiguous match."

Thus, the above constructors WOULD be safe, but would force any implementation to specify *explicitly* what type they wanted to pass in, so the compiler could infer properly. Since your methods take in specific enums, however, *they* are distinguishable to the compiler, making the above code pass the compiler without issue.

If you wanted to avoid the factory methods, you could do the following

```
var A = new MyClass((MyEnumOne)0);
var B = new MyClass((MyEnumTwo)0);
```

Make sure to read up on explicit and implicit conversions, and how the compiler resolves overloads.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve in the safest possible way is as follows:

l_param.DbType = (DbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DbType), param.dataType);

```
public readonly MyEnumOne E1;
public readonly MyEnumTwo E2;

private MyClass(MyEnumOne e1)
{
    E1 = (MyEnumTwo)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumTwo), e1);
}
```

Similarly for the other conversion.

Comment: Sorry if someone got it the wrong way. I don't want to parse from E1 to E2 or viceversa. What I want is for the correct constructor to be called, no matter if the one who called the function uses the function without being explicit enough, but thanks anyway ;)